# Custom template style ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Доброго времени суток, у меня есть две ошибки, которые я пока не могу решить.
Заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

1. При наведении курсора мыши на ComboBox, он выделяется цветом. Но если в конструкторе XAML поменять Background у ComboBox, он больше не выделяется цветом.
2. Мне нужно привязать цвет Background и Border ComboBox'a к Background и Border выпадающего списка ComboBox'a. Но чтобы при наведении курсора мыши на ComboBox, выпадающий список не менял цвет Background и Border на цвет выделения ComboBox'a.

Код:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
        <Path Grid.Column="1" Data="M0,0 L0,2 L4,6 L8,2 L8,0 L4,4 Z" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="Black"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ToggleButton
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        ClickMode="Press"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate}"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter 
                        Margin="5, 3, 0, 3"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"                              
                        Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}" 
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"/>

                    <Popup AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Slide" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen}">
                        <Grid MinWidth="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.MaxDropDownHeight}">
                            <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"/>
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="0,1,1,1">
                                <ItemsPresenter KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Aqua"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует [порядок применения различных источников значения dependency property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence): значение, выставляемое непосредственно, сильнее значения из триггера, а значение из триггера сильнее значения из сеттера стиля.

Поэтому непосредственно присвоенное вами значение «заруливает» всё.

Напишите стиль.